# How to get closest repeated values in array to target value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

```js
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
  var SwitchesByNumberOfPorts = [48,24];
  var Target = 115;
  var Target_Copy = Target;
  var needSwitches = [];

  SwitchesByNumberOfPorts.forEach(function(ports) {
    while(Target_Copy >= ports) {
      Target_Copy -= ports;
      needSwitches.push(ports);
    }
  });

  var portsCalculated = needSwitches.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

  if (portsCalculated<Target){
    var RemainingTarget = Target - portsCalculated;
    var AdditionalPorts = SwitchesByNumberOfPorts.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return (Math.abs(curr - RemainingTarget) < Math.abs(prev - RemainingTarget) ? curr : prev);
    });
    needSwitches.push(AdditionalPorts)
  }
 $("#result").html(needSwitches.join(", "));
 //console.log(needSwitches);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Loading...</div>
```

The query is regarding a JavaScript calculation to archive the number of network switches needed based on the numbers of ports provided by the customer.

The network switches available are : 24 and 48 ports per unit.

For example if the client currently have 115 ports, the most optimum solution to provide will be 2 switches  of 48 ports and 1 switch of 24 ports leaving 5 ports available.

I'm looking for algorithms or function in JavaScript that will allow me to add an array of values [24,48] and get the closest result to the target 115.

```
var SwitchesByNumberOfPorts = [24,48]
var Target = 115
getClosestArrayValues(SwitchesByNumberOfPorts , Target)

// Expected Result  [48,48,24] #120 ports
```

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165950/subset-whose-sum-gets-closest-to-saturating-some-bound

Comment: Based on Roberto Answer to my query I generated this fiddle example.
https://jsfiddle.net/victorsaly/jurr57cz/

Comment: *get the closest result to the target 115* <-- hm, no, you are not looking for the closest result as per your comment below [roberto thomàs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339014/1647737). Perhaps you could update the question to reflect this. However, if you are really just interested in 48 and 24 port switches, it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. sort high to low

`sorted = vals.sort((a,b) => b>a)`

2. For each element, subtract from the target value until you can't any more, and keep track

`sorted.forEach(v => {
      while(target_copy >= v) {
        target_copy -= v
        needs.push(v)
      }
    })`

3. however, this will leave the last purchase needed off, so at the end, check if you need to buy the smallest one again

   if (target_copy > 0) { needs.push(sorted[sorted.length -1]) }

Here's a js console showing it in action:

```
function seek (set, target) {
 let needs = []
 let sorted = set.sort((a,b) => b>a)
 sorted.forEach(v => {
   while(target >= v) {
     target -= v
     needs.push(v)
   }
 })
 if(target > 0) { needs.push(sorted[sorted.length - 1]) }
 return needs
}
undefined
seek([48,24],115)
(3) [48, 48, 24]
```

Comment: Your solution is fast and 'works' but doesn't provide optimal results. E.g. `seek([30, 20, 15], 35)` evaluates to `[30, 15]` while the optimal solution would be `[20, 15]`.

Comment: Thanks le_m in my case I need to take into accounts the highest port switch and the solution provided by roberto tomás covered quite well  that's the reason he's sorting by hightest value first. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sieve for this. Sort the input values from large to small if necessary, and create an empty sieve:

```
{0:[]}
```

Then for each value in the input, iterate over the values in the sieve (including the ones you've just added in this step) and add the value to them, until you've reached or passed the target. In the example, we start with 48:

```
{0:[], 48:[48], 96:[48,48], 144:[48,48,48]}
```

Do the same for the next value 24:

```
{0:[], 24:[24], 48:[48], 72:[48,24], 96:[48,48], 120:[48,48,24], 144:[48,48,48]}
```

When the new value you create, e.g. 24+24=48, is already present, don't replace it, so that the smallest number of values is used, i.e. 48 instead of 24+24, 48+24 instead of 24+24+24, etc...

When you've looked at all the values, take the first item in the sieve that is equal to or greater than the target. In the example, that is:

```
120:[48,48,24]
```

---

For the example input [30, 20, 15] and target 35, that would be:

```
{0:[]}
{0:[], 30:[30], 60:[30,30]}
{0:[], 20:[20], 30:[30], 40:[20,20], 60:[30,30]}
{0:[], 15:[15], 20:[20], 30:[30], 35:[20,15], 40:[20,20], 60:[30,30]}
```

And the result is:

```
35:[20,15]
```

---

*NOTE: If you have a preference for the use of values other than high-to-low, just sort the values in order of preference before creating the sieve; e.g. using [20, 15, 30] will result in 65:[20,15,15,15] instead of 65:[30,20,15].*

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @robertotomás When a problem is similar to coin change, a sieve is always an option, especially if the values are small.